# Schema File not run in tests

Tags: laravel, testing

When I run tests I call migrate:fresh. The schema file is not running. I'm using mysql database for testing. migrate:fresh runs well in other environments. please anyone has an idea?

This is the command I'm using:

```
Artisan::call('migrate:fresh')
```

Comment: Do you get any error ? did you check the logs ? have you tried `\Artisan::call('migrate:fresh')` with anti slash at the start for namespace

Comment: Out of curiousity, why don't you use the [`RefreshDatabase`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) trait?

Answer (score 2):

This probably happens because your test database doesn't have the same name as your dumped database, so laravel can't find the migration.
A work around could be manually specify the dump path to the RefreshDatabase trait like that:

```php
namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication, RefreshDatabase;

    protected function migrateFreshUsing()
    {
        return ['--schema-path' => 'database/schema/mysql-schema.dump'];
    }
}
```